# First month customers amount

Tags: sql, range, teradata, monthcalendar

Teradta - SQL
I need to show (new_col) the amount in all months only to clients of the first month

have:

```
date        cust sum
2020-04-01  1    100
2020-04-01  2    100
2020-05-01  1    100
2020-05-01  3    100
2020-06-01  4    100
2020-06-01  2    100
```

Need:

```
date        cust sum  new_col
2020-04-01  1    100  100
2020-04-01  2    110  110
2020-05-01  1    120  120
2020-05-01  3    100  null
2020-06-01  4    100  null
2020-06-01  2    140  140
```

Comment: `Russian:` Какова логика нулевого значения? `English:` What is the logic of the null value?

Comment: What have you attempted?  You need to show some effort if you expect help.

Comment: The new_col column should contain sum only for those clients (cust) that are in the first month. In the example, this is the date 2020-04-01 and cust 1,2. For the rest (3,4) - null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you need a *Group Min*.

Assuming the date is always the 1st of month:

```
case
  when min(date) over (partition by cust) -- min date for customer
     = min(date) over ()                  -- min date overall
  then sum
end
```